# Symfony Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: json ~~ unknown

Tags: symfony

While learning Symfony, I decided to play around with roles. I need to get all users who have the role 'ROLE_MODERATOR' in order to send them emails

Created the following method in the repository

```
public function getModerators() {
    $role = 'ROLE_MODERATOR';

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.roles = :role')
        ->setParameter('role', $role)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

As a result I get an error

```
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: json ~~ unknown HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Maybe the framework has some standard functions for getting users by roles?

Comment: you should probably add the doctrine tag and mention which kind of database you're using. But in the end, you're using `=`  to compare a json field with a scalar, which will always fail (unless some evil conversion is going on). You might have to add/use the appropriate json function, which *might* be included here: https://github.com/ScientaNL/DoctrineJsonFunctions

Comment: You can't do this. Because of roles inheritance, a user could have the moderator role even it isn't in the database (for example "admin" which also includes the "moderator" right).